# NSHTTPCookieStorage shared across multiple apps

Tags: ios, nshttpcookie, nshttpcookiestorage

How do I share a NSHTTPCookieStorage across multiple iOS apps? I want MYAPP A and MYAPP B to use the same cookies, so I can switch between them easily.

I found the following method in `NSHTTPCookieStorage.h` but did not see it mentioned in the [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSHTTPCookieStorage_Class/).

```
+ (NSHTTPCookieStorage *)sharedCookieStorageForGroupContainerIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier NS_AVAILABLE(10_11, 9_0);
```

Answer (score 3):

Answering my own question for the 6 other people who might run across this in the future...

In my research, I have found that `sharedCookieStorageForGroupContainerIdentifier:` is new functionality designed to work exclusively with NSURLSession, and allows you to directly specify cookie stores other than `sharedHTTPCookieStorage`.

Unfortunately, this functionality is not backwards compatible with the `NSURLConnection` suite of functionality, as `NSURLConnection` [automatically persists its cookies to `sharedHTTPCookieStorage`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12022541/does-nsurlconnection-automatically-persist-cookies-sent-from-server), and this behavior cannot be overridden.

**TL;DR: If you want your own Cookie storage use NSURLSession.**