# How do i maintain session state with a native mobile client?

Tags: iphone, session

Considering there are no cookies stored on mobile phones (or are there?) I know that I cant use cookies with mobile phones, so would I just pass the session_id back and forth for the mobile client?

What would be some approaches I can do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2053568/managing-http-cookies-on-iphone)

There is e good discussion about cookies trasmitted via NSURLRequest